# Почему не срабатывает исключение?

Tags: php

```
try{
     1/0;
}catch (\DivisionByZeroError  $error){
        echo $error->getMessage();
}
```

По идее должен сработать catch, но почему-то выводит

> Warning: Division by zero in C:\path\index.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Деление на ноль является синтаксической ошибкой. Поэтому её правильно обрабатывать как в [примере](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.exceptions.php), используя `throw`:

```
function inverse($x) {
  if (!$x) {
    throw new Exception('Деление на ноль.');
  }
  return 1/$x;
}

 try {
   echo inverse(5) . "\n";
   echo inverse(0) . "\n";
 } catch (Exception $e) {
   echo 'Выброшено исключение: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
 }
```